# How can I use an OSM XML in OpenLayers3?

Tags: xml, openstreetmap, openlayers-3

How can I use an OSM (OpenStreetMap) XML in OpenLayers3 ? I have read the API and I have tried to adapt the only example available on OL3 site but nothing has worked.

I have got the OSM XML from there: http://opensnowmap.org/iframes/data.html (the file is called planet_pistes.osm)

My purpose is to display those data in a map with OL3. On this website http://opensnowmap.org/, it is displayed with OL2.

Does someone knows how to do it or has a working example beside the one in OL3 site ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is plenty of ways to do what you want, but no straight one.

To make tiles the way opensnowmap does, the code from opensnowmap is here:
    https://github.com/yvecai/opensnowmap.org
    https://github.com/yvecai/mapnik-opensnowmap.org
    https://github.com/yvecai/data-opensnowmap.org

If you want to make your own tiles from the data, one good entry point to learn is 
    http://switch2osm.org/fr/

Yves - Webmaster opensnowmap.org

Comment: By the way, maybe this question could be a duplicate of  [169387](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169387/using-local-openstreetmap-osm-map-with-openlayers-3).